# How to change number of characters used for indentation when writing XML with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to change the default indentation of XDocument from 2 to 3, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.  How can this be done?

I'm familiar with `XmlTextWriter` and have used code as such:

```
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string destinationFile = "C:\myPath\results.xml";
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(destinationFile, null);
            writer.Indentation = 3;
            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            // Add elements, etc

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

For another project I used `XDocument` because it works better for my implementation similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Source file has indentation of 3
            string sourceFile = @"C:\myPath\source.xml";
            string destinationFile = @"C:\myPath\results.xml";

            List<XElement> devices = new List<XElement>();

            XDocument template = XDocument.Load(sourceFile);        

            // Add elements, etc

            template.Save(destinationFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Save` takes `XmlWriter`... - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336977.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As @John Saunders and @sa_ddam213 noted, `new XmlWriter` is deprecated so I dug a little deeper and learned how to change indentation using XmlWriterSettings.  The `using` statement idea I got from @sa_ddam213.

I replaced `template.Save(destinationFile);` with the following:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "   ";  // Indent 3 Spaces

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(destinationFile, settings))
{                    
    template.Save(writer);
}
```

This gave me the 3 space indentation that I needed.  If more spaces are needed, just add them to `IndentChars` or `"\t"` can be used for tab.

Comment: +1, good find, I removed mine as I was getting a lot of negitive feedback, and your solution is a good workaround other than using the old `XmlTextWriter`